# My kids have no Social Security number

Tags: passport

My kids were born in Germany.  I'm a U.S. citizen.  I'm trying to figure out how we get them a SSN and/or get them first a US passport.  I can't apply for Birth of a U.S. Citizen Abroad because we are in Texas. I really don't now what to do.

Comment: Do your kids have German birth certificates showing that you are their parent?  If so, I think you should be able to apply for passports without the CRBA by presenting secondary evidence of citizenship.  How did your kids get into the US without US passports?

Comment: First of all, do you know if your kids are US citizens? To determine that, were you a US citizen when they were born? Was the other parent a US citizen when they were born? How long were you physically present in the US before their birth, and at what age?

Comment: Please [edit] the answers to the above questions into your question.